# Django: Making a master site using django tenants

Tags: python, django

I would want to make my Blog django project tenant aware, whereby I have a master site and two tenants. I have been able to create the tenants, the problem is with the master site. I would want the master site to show all tenant articles. How do I go about this?

I have created my master site from the `settings.py` file below, I get the error below:

```
ProgrammingError at /
relation "articles_article" does not exist
LINE 1: ...cle"."thumb", "articles_article"."author_id" FROM "articles_...
```

settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition
SHARED_APPS = (
    'django_tenants',  # mandatory
    'customers',  # you must list the app where your tenant model resides in

    'django.contrib.contenttypes',

    # everything below here is optional
    # 'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    # 'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)

TENANT_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    # 'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'articles',
    'accounts',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = list(SHARED_APPS) + [app for app in TENANT_APPS if app not in SHARED_APPS]

TENANT_MODEL = "customers.Client" # app.Model

TENANT_DOMAIN_MODEL = "customers.Domain"  # app.Model

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django_tenants.middleware.main.TenantMainMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Reader.urls'
PUBLIC_SCHEMA_NAME = 'public'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Reader.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_tenants.postgresql_backend',
        'NAME': 'tenant_blog',
        'USER': 'posts',
        'HOST': 'locst',
        'PORT': 5432,
        'PASSWORD': 'ps',
    }
}
  
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
    
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "django_tenants.files.storage.TenantFileSystemStorage"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "django_tenants.staticfiles.storage.TenantStaticFilesStorage"

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MULTITENANT_RELATIVE_STATIC_ROOT = ""

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

MULTITENANT_RELATIVE_MEDIA_ROOT = ""  # (default: create sub-directory for each tenant)

DATABASE_ROUTERS = (
    'django_tenants.routers.TenantSyncRouter',
)
```

Comment: The error suggests that you've got an article app which doesn't exist in the database but django is trying to access it's table.

Comment: @markwalker_ if I add articles app in shared apps, articles will not be tenant specific. Any help?

Comment: I've never used this tenants app, but what this error tells us is that Django has loaded the app & queried the database for the articles app. But the article tables don't exist. Have you made the migrations & ran them?

Comment: As you are using Django-Tenants can you state the url you are going to. As I think you are using the wrong URL. If you want to use a tenant you need to use subdomain otherwise it won't know which tenant you should go too.  I suggest watching the youtube video which is located on the bottom of the Django-Tenant github  page.